# Micro and macro temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

I'm looking at the equipartition theorem and trying to understand the definition of temperature microscopically and macroscopically. Macroscopically I understand that you have the zeroth law, and this tells you that there is a quantity that's the same between two bodies in thermal equilibrium, so you can define this to be the temperature. This seems like a reasonable way to define temperature, always relative to something else.

Then if I look at the equipartition theorem, the parts saying that the energy must be split evenly between the three degrees of freedom of space is intuitive to me. So then you can have eg. $$\frac{1}{2}m \langle v_x^2 \rangle = \alpha T,$$ which I think makes sense as a microscopic definition of temperature; that it arises from the motion of particles on the average

So then it seems that $\alpha$ should somehow be fixed by relating microscopic and macroscopic definitions of temperature. But how do we choose $\alpha$? I know $k_B$ as kind of, the necessary conversion factor with the right units to convert between temperature and energy, but why do we have half of this in the equipartition theorem?

I think you could measure $T$ and $m$, and $\langle v_x^2 \rangle$ from some kind of experiment, and define $$\alpha := \frac{1}{2} \frac{m \langle v_x^2 \rangle}{T},$$ which would give you your microscopic definition of temperature, in terms of KE of the particles, and a scaling factor $\alpha$ to relate to what you measure on the thermometer. So how does this relate to Boltzman's constant? Why would we want to have a half of that here, and could we define it this way if we wanted to?

Comment: look at kinetic temperature http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html

Comment: @annav what I understand from that link is; if you only have equilibrium temperature and kinetic temperature then this is not enough to fix the $\alpha$ to be $k_B/2$ in the equipartition theorem. Once you introduce entropic temperature, this constant will be fixed. Do you agree?

Comment: I do not know enough about entropic temperature. may be this link will answer your question https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267586215_The_Usefulness_of_Entropic_Average_Temperatures